# How to "move" a file currently being written-to by a process (bash, copy, truncate)

Tags: bash, mv

What's the best way to automatically rotate a file in BASH to prevent the possibility of data loss if that file is sporadically being written-to?

For example, I want to do this, but I think it's possible for data loss to occur due to the time between the commands where the destination file doesn't exist

```
mv foo.bar foo.bar-$(date "+%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
touch foo.bar
chown user1:user1 foo.bar
chmod 0600 foo.bar
```

What's the best way to improve the above BASH commands such that there is no possibility for the loss or corruption of data that's being written to the file `foo.bar`?

Comment: "file is sporadically being written-to" – How? Opened, kept open and sporadically being written-to? Or sporadically being opened, written-to and closed right away?

Comment: Will the process that writes to the file not create a new one automatically if it does not exist?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I'm looking for a solution that can handle all of those cases, if possible

Comment: @forest I'm looking for a solution that will support both cases, if possible.

Comment: @MichaelAltfield So you basically want an atomic way to "rename file and create new file with specific permissions"? What about a fifo? That will buffer whatever you need while you move other files.

Comment: See [this article](http://jdebp.info/FGA/do-not-use-logrotate.html) for some insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the writing application won't create a new file on its own and data it wants to write will be lost if it can't find the file to write to, you will need to ensure that there is no period during which the file does not exist. One possible solution would be to use hardlinks to simulate an atomic "a->b and b->c" rename. This could be done with something like the following:

```
ln foo.bar foo.bar-$(date "+%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
touch foo.bar.new
mv foo.bar.new foo.bar
```

Any writes which occur between the link before the rename will be mirrored to the backup file.

This works because `mv` uses the `rename()` syscall when possible. When that syscall is used to replace another file, there is no period where an application cannot `open()` the file by its name. A process that tries to open it will either see it with its old inode or its new inode. If it accesses it by its old inode (i.e. `rename()` hasn't returned yet), then it will be opening the backup file. If it access it by its new inode, it will be opening the freshly-created and empty file.